# Why is there no access to all document resources?

Tags: carrot2

I would like to understand why I can not continue my work with Carrot2. A message appears saying "Our apologies, the following processing error has occurred:
org.carrot2.source.etools.IpBannedException: org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Forbidden"
There is a problem with eTools, Wiki, PUT document sources (31/07/19) into Online version. I try to work with the downloaded version of the programme, but no document source does not work. Could you solve this problem and how long it will take?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please see here:

http://project.carrot2.org/faq.html#ipbanned

> We provide the search interface as a demo of the technology and we use a partnership with a company called [Comcepta (eTools)](http://www.comcepta.com/) for providing a limited number of free search requests. Unfortunately, some people have been abusing this free service and we had to introduce per-IP limitations.
>
> If you wish to extend your query limits please install Carrot2 locally and contact Comcepta for custom query limit arrangements.
>
> Apologies for the inconvenience.